# Predicting Missing Features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, missing-data

I have "millions" of items each having N binary features. When a feature is "0" it could be that the information is simply missing. So, given the data with the currently observed 1's, I would like to have a probability of the "0" features being "1".

I am thinking this can be a Neural network with all features as input and same as output. But then I don't know how the training would work. I don't have ground truth.

I would like some help expressing my problem and hopefully not reinvent the wheel. Is this is a classical problem in ML, and what approach can be applied?

Comment: What about the ground truth? I mean it is not clear to me whether you have a dataset correctly labeled to make a model learn against.

Comment: We don't have a ground truth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach could be the following: suppose $i \in \{0,1\}^d$ is the vector you want to predict which of the $0$ entries could be $1$ and $j \in J$ the rest of the feature vectors. Take the $k$ nearest neighbors, under some suitable distance ([Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)). For each $0$ entry the probabilities could be the percentage of the $k$ nearest neighbors that have $1$ in the corresponding entry.

This problem has been extensively study in the [collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) community. The best known example being the [Netflix Prize](https://www.netflixprize.com/). This [blog post](https://medium.com/@victorkohler/item-item-collaborative-filtering-with-binary-or-unary-data-e8f0b465b2c3) provides a nice explanation of this approarch for binary data.

Another, more involved, approach is [matrix completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion), in particular check this [reference](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5005-probabilistic-low-rank-matrix-completion-with-adaptive-spectral-regularization-algorithms.pdf). If you are into deep learning check [this](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3141950).

Comment: Brilliant! this seems to be exactly my setting. I will read through your pointers, thank you.